# Intersection of a directed family of large sets

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Fix an $0\lt\varepsilon \lt 1$ (you may assume, if required, that $\varepsilon\lt \frac{1}{2}$ or, indeed, that $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small for any argument you may wish to do). Let $G$ be a family of subsets of $[0,1]$ such that every element of $G$ has Lebesgue measure greater than $1-\varepsilon$ and which is downward directed, i.e. for every $X,Y\in G$ there is a $Z\in G$ satisfying $Z\subseteq X\cap Y$. Assume in addition that for all $X,Y\in G$ the symmetric difference $X\triangle Y$ has nonzero measure.

Is $\bigcap G$ necessarily measurable and, if so, does it have measure at least $1-\varepsilon$?

Both questions are easily seen to have a positive answer if $G$ is countable, but we make no such assumption here. What I have tried to do is to approximate the elements of $G$ from below by compact sets and then trying to show that this derived family of compact sets has the finite intersection property. I can't quite get it to work, but this would at least show that $\bigcap G$ is nonempty. Then again, I'm not sure how this would help in answering the actual questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{(F_{\alpha}, r_{\alpha}) : \alpha < 2^{\omega} \}$ list, cofinally often, all pairs $(F, r)$ where $F$ is a finite subset of $[0, 1]$ and $r$ is a rational in $(1-\epsilon, 1)$. Construct $G = \{A_{\alpha} : \alpha < 2^{\omega}\}$ inductively such that each $A_{\alpha} = (0, x_{\alpha}) \backslash F_{\alpha}$ where $r_{\alpha} < x_{\alpha} < 1$. Also ensure that $\alpha < \beta < 2^{\omega}$ implies $x_{\alpha} \neq x_{\beta}$. Then $G$ satisfies all your requirements and $\bigcap G = \phi$.

Comment: I guess the natural questions now are to identify (in terms of known [cardinal invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) of the continuum) the least cardinals $\kappa_1$ such that there is $G$ with $|G|=\kappa_1$ and $\bigcap G$ empty, and $\kappa_2$ such that there is a $G$ of size $\kappa_2$ with $\bigcap G$ non-measurable.

Comment: This is very nice. To be honest it seems I didn't really ask the question I wanted to, but the problem was interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Dear Andres, I think the construction can be modified to conclude $\kappa_1 = \text{ cov(Null)}$ and $\kappa_2 = \text{ non(Null)}$.

Comment: @user87216 Yes, I was actually here just to leave a comment mentioning this. Nice question.

Answer (score 2):

[**Edit:** The answer below refers to the original version of the question, where the sets in $G$ were not required to be different modulo the null ideal.]

Not necessarily. Pick a non-measurable set $T\subset[0,1]$, and for each finite set $F$ of points in $[0,1]\setminus T$, put in $G$ the set $[0,1]\setminus F$. Then $\bigcap G=T$. By replacing $T$ with the empty set, we see that even if we require that $\bigcap G$ is measurable, we cannot assert any non-trivial lower bounds on its measure.

Comment: What if we assume that all elements of $G$ are distinct modulo the null ideal?

Comment: Ah, that would be more interesting. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: I'll edit the question.